# user input to put the output in descending order

Tags: python

User input where the output would be sorted in descending order.

E.g., Enter a number:

Do you want to input more:

if yes print Enter another number

if answer no

break the arugument and sort the output in descending order.

I have used `raw_input` for questing and taking while loop for running the code. but it is sorting only the 1st output and last output in descending order

```
a = raw_input("Enter a number: ")
while True:
    b = raw_input("Do you want to input more: ")
    c = raw_input("Enter another number:")
    if b == 'yes':
        print (c)
        continue
    elif b == 'no':
        my_list = [a,c]
        my_list.sort(reverse=True)
        print(my_list)
        break
```

i expect the code to runned successfully

```
Enter a number:2
Do you want to input more:yes
Enter another number:3
Do you want to input more:yes
Enter another number:4
Do you want to input more:no
[4,3,2]
```

Comment: 1) your list only contains 2 elements a & c. 2) the sort should be performed on integers. You don't convert your strings to integers. Try 10, 2...

Comment: Use input instead of raw_input for Python 3.x

Comment: @call me programmer, please accept the answer that helped you solve your problem by clicking on the tick sign beside it, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

In **Python 3.x,** use `input()` instead of `raw_input()`

Create a `list` to append the user input into it, so it can later be sorted.

```
input_List = []
input_List.append(int(input("Enter a number: ")))

while True:
    b = input("Do you want to input more: ")
    if b == 'yes':
        input_List.append(int(input("Enter a number: ")))
    elif b == 'no':
        input_List.sort(reverse=True)
        break

print(input_List)
```

OUTPUT:

```
Enter a number: 5
Do you want to input more: yes
Enter a number: 7
Do you want to input more: yes
Enter a number: 90
Do you want to input more: no
[90, 7, 5]
```

Comment: at least some answer which has been properly tested and has some explanation

Answer (score 0):

It should look like this:

```
a = input("Enter a number: ")
l = [int(a)]
while True:
    b = input("Do you want to input more: ")
    if b == 'yes':
        c = input("Enter another number:")
        l.append(int(c))
    elif b == 'no':
        l.sort(reverse=True)
        print(l)
        break
```

Comment: have you tested this?

Comment: l = list(int(a))    'int' object is not iterable

Comment: My bad, fixed it :)

Answer (score 0):

A lot of logical mistakes and also more subtle ones

- `raw_input` returns a string, you're not going to get a proper numerical sort unless you convert to integer.
- the yes/no question logic is broken, comes too late...
- you never use `append` on your list, it will always contain 2 elements. `my_list = [a,c]` makes no sense.

My proposal:

```
# this is for retrocompatibility. Python 3 users will ditch raw_input altogether
try:
    raw_input
except NameError:
    raw_input = input   # for python 3 users :)

# initialize the list with the first element
my_list = [int(raw_input("Enter a number: "))]

while True:
    b = raw_input("Do you want to input more: ")
    if b == 'yes':
        # add one element
        my_list.append(int(raw_input("Enter another number:")))
    elif b == 'no':
        my_list.sort(reverse=True)
        print(my_list)
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your newly inputted values to a list rather than recreate a new variable on each iteration.

Here's the revised code, using `input` instead of `raw_input` for Python 3 compatibility:

```py
a = input('Enter number: ')

# create a list, add the first number
# we use a list so we can append each new number that is added
my_list = [a]

while True:
    b = input("Do you want to input more: ")
    if b == 'yes':
        inputted = input("Enter another number: ")
        my_list.append(inputted)
    elif b == 'no':
        break

my_list.sort(reverse=True)  # reverse sort list
print(my_list)
```

Notice that we append the newly entered values to an array that was declared **before** the loop started so that the values are stored between iterations. Then we sort the list at the end.

Answer (score -1):

The following will work

```
my_list = []
a = int(raw_input("Enter a number: "))
my_list.append(a)
while True:
    b = raw_input("Do you want to input more: ")
    if b == 'yes':
        c = int(raw_input("Enter another number:"))
        my_list.append(c)
        continue
    elif b == 'no':
        my_list.sort(reverse=True)
        print(my_list)
        break
```

Output:

```
Enter a number: 4
Do you want to input more: yes
Enter another number:3
Do you want to input more: yes
Enter another number:8
Do you want to input more: no
['8', '4', '3']
```

Comment: sorting is alphanumeric because you're using python 3. That's incorrect if you input 10, and 2.

Comment: my bad, i was testing in Python 3. forgot to change the code